# É possível fazer biblioteca estática (.lib) com função inline?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, biblioteca, inline

Uso Visual Studio 2019 Community. Perguntei no fórum e não recebi respostas.

Quero saber se é possível (se sim, como) em VC++ declarar (sem corpo) uma função ou métodos numa classe num ".h", definir no ".cpp" e compilar para ".lib" de maneira que se tenha controle das propriedades da função, incluindo inline e forceinline.

Isto é visando os benefícios do adiantamento da compilação de corpo com .lib, possibilidade de fazer includes em ".cpp" sem fazer no ".h" para não aparecer no IntelliSense e encapsular detalhes internos de compilação e outras coisas sem as limitações. Não encontrei meios nem tenstando e nem pesquisando.

Alguém pode me responder?

Comment: Obs.: sei que o mais recomendado é simplesmente o padrão, deixar o compilador otimizar como quiser, mas eu quero saber se posso usar esses recursos com essa liberdade.

Comment: Meu chute é que não, funções e métodos inline pertencem ao .h, o compilador trata quase como se fosse uma macro. Fazer isso com código binário de uma função já compilada é muito mais difícil, pois esse código binário presume que está "sozinho" dentro do stack frame e pode estar fazendo algumas bruxarias de otimização.